# Jruby gem error win32-service for rsense

Tags: emacs, rubygems, jruby

I am trying to install Rsense, I am following the directions from here [Rsense Docs](http://cx4a.org/software/rsense/manual.html#Install_RSense)

RSENSE_HOME is set but i cannot install the jruby win32-service to complete the steps to have the rsense service started at boot.

This is the full error, I also ran as error suggested specifying jruby version. Any ideas on completing the install?

```
C:\Users\RenshawFamily>echo %RSENSE_HOME%
C:\Rsense

C:\Users\RenshawFamily>jruby -S gem install win32-service
Fetching: win32-api-1.4.8.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing win32-service:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    c:/jruby-1.6.3/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb
WARNING: JRuby does not support native extensions or the `mkmf' library very wel
l.
Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.
checking for strncpy_s()... IOError: Cannot run program "cc" (in directory "C:\j
ruby-1.6.3\lib\ruby\gems\1.8\gems\win32-api-1.4.8\ext"): CreateProcess error=2,
The system cannot find the file specified
     popen at org/jruby/RubyIO.java:3540
    xpopen at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:323
      open at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:260
    xpopen at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:316
 egrep_cpp at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:538
 have_func at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:758
checking_for at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:652
  postpone at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:286
      open at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:260
  postpone at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:286
      open at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:260
  postpone at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:282
checking_for at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:651
 have_func at c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/site_ruby/shared/mkmf.rb:755
    (root) at extconf.rb:9
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=c:/jruby-1.6.3/bin/jruby


Gem files will remain installed in c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-a
pi-1.4.8 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/jruby-1.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/win32-api-1.4.8/ext/gem_
make.out

C:\Users\RenshawFamily>jruby -S gem install win32-service --ruby=c:/jruby-1.6.3/
bin/jruby
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (OptionParser::InvalidOption)
invalid option: --ruby=c:/jruby-1.6.3/bin/jruby
```

Answer (score 0):

`win32-service` uses C extensions.  Gems that use C extensions are generally not compatible with JRuby, although there are efforts being made to address that - [see here for background](http://blog.headius.com/2010/07/what-jruby-c-extension-support-means-to.html)

Are you able to use MRI/CRuby for your project?

Or you could use a java based service management lib, but then that might not work with emacs/rsense.

Or you could roll up your sleeves and make `win32-service` JRuby compatible!

Comment: if rubinius comes to fruition will Jruby be able to draw on those extensions? Or re-write the C extensions to ruby?

Comment: Hmmm rubinius is a ruby implementation, not an extension.  I think it may have the same problems with C extensions as JRuby.  Hopefully it will be able to use the same solutions.  If an extention *can be* written in ruby, it probably is.  C extensions are often wrappers for c libs (Image Magic, native DB drivers, etc) and sometimes for performance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when installing the win-32-service gem. This solved it:

```
gem install win32-service --platform=mswin32
```

So your command should probably be

```
jruby -S gem install win32-service --platform=mswin32
```

although I'm guessing here.